# Getting error while writing the shell scripting command for getting the type of git object

Tags: git, shell

```
# Fetching the git object from second question.

for item in $( ls q2/.git/objects)
do
   
   
      if [ ${#item} == 2 ];
      then 
      to=$item;
      
      for temp in $( ls q2/.git/objects/$item)
      do
      to+=$temp
      done
      
      
      ans= git cat-file -t $to;

      fi``your text``
      

done
```

Error :

```
fatal: git cat-file: could not get object info
```

Comment: Under `.git/objects` there are two folders `info/` and `pack/`, which you need to exclude. However, it's not a good method to iterate over objects this way. If `git gc` is executed in this repository, `.git/objects` will have only `info/` and `pack/` left. The other folders, of which the names are 2 digits, with files under them, or loose objects, will be gone. They are packed into `.git/objects/pack/*.pack`. If you intend to do so, remember to exclude `info/` and `pack/`.